# How to upload a list of large files using django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, chunks, multiple-file-upload

I know how to **upload large files** using the [django-chunked-upload](https://github.com/juliomalegria/django-chunked-upload) package. It's an elegant solution to upload one file using an `<input type="file"/>` tag.

I haven't found anything allowing me to upload more than one file with this package.

In my case, I try to create a drag-drop zone in which the user could drop multiple files. With the JavaScript, I obtain a `FileList` object I can iterate to get `File` objects. I would like to send this files chunked to my Django app.

The problem is that package work using the `<input type="file"/>` with a CSRF protection and it seems to be forbidden to change the file present in it.

Does anyone know a solution to interact with this type of `input` if files are already known in JavaScript or if other Django solution exists?